# How to setup logger in pyspark for multiple modules?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have been trying to setup pyspark logger for multiple modules.
For base script,  I am able to set it up and use logger but unable to find any way of bringing that logger to other modules.
Need some help on that aspect.

```
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("INFO")
log_4j = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logger = log_4j.LogManager.getLogger(__name__)
```

Used this code to setup the logger in base script.